# Executing AWS command : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

aws command works fine as root user. But, throws error under normal user(balaji). I have copied the   output  of both ( root and balaji) below.

```
balaji@ip-xx-xx-xx-33:~$ aws
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 29, in <module>
    import botocore.configloader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/configloader.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.compat import six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/compat.py", line 26, in <module>
    from urllib3 import exceptions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'
balaji@ip-xx-xx-xx-33]:~$ sudo -i
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-33~]# aws
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: the following arguments are required: command
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-33 ~]#
```

Wondering what causes this error/issue?

Comment: How did you create the user balaji?

Comment: useradd -c balaji -s /bin/bash -m balaji

Comment: I did create my user and everything was working fine for me. What I did was : sudo adduser pacifist --> sudo su pacifist --> aws. AWS commands are running fine this way.

Comment: Other user doesn't have sudo access. Has the same issue. With sudo no issues.

Comment: Did you try creating the user like the way I did?

Comment: I aways use sudo or root to create user.

Comment: [set your user path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux-al2017.html)

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/balaji/bin

Comment: install with `--user` option using pip